# Unable to Convert to Date

Tags: sql, oracle, to-char

I am trying to return just the date from a datetime field
When I run the Select Claus with just the first line, it work as expected.
But when I add the second line, I receive From keyword not found error.

```
SELECT To_Char(t.inc_date_time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS Date_Time,
       To_Char(t.inc_date_time,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS Date
FROM tbl t
FETCH first 10 rows only
```

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The To_Char function is product specific.)

Comment: plaese add the tag for the used dbms

Comment: I guess `Date` is a reserved work (AS Date --> AS Date1)

Comment: date is an Oracle reserved word, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_reserved_words. Delimit as `"Date"`, or chose some non-reserved column alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Oracle, `DATE` is a reserved word and you cannot use it as an unquoted identifier. Either change your query to use a different identifier:

```sql
SELECT To_Char(t.inc_date_time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS Date_Time,
       To_Char(t.inc_date_time,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS dt
FROM tbl t
FETCH first 10 rows only
```

Or quote the identifier:

```sql
SELECT To_Char(t.inc_date_time,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AS Date_Time,
       To_Char(t.inc_date_time,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS "DATE"
FROM tbl t
FETCH first 10 rows only
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=328fb599b27ebc14c578135fe2585b0a)*

Comment: While double-quoting will work to resolve the original problem, and so should be mentioned, I think it is remiss to mention it without a statement discouraging its use.  Two reasons. One, it leads to case dependency, which goes against the grain of oracle design. Two in cases such as this, it "encourages" the use of reserved words for object names, which in turn leads to very confusing code that will be inordinately hard to debug in the future.

Comment: @EdStevens Its a community wiki answer. Feel free to edit it yourself.